# div below another div, each with 100% width and height of screen

Tags: html, css, sass, responsive-design

I make one page layout website. I need every div with 100% width and height. Div1 is ok, but how can I make div2 and div3 with 100% height of screen after scroll? 100vh is longer. I need it for different height, so I can't use fixed height.
(sorry for bad english)

```
div1 {
       position: relative;
       background-color: #fff;
       border-radius: 12px;
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%; 
}
```

[image: **enter image description here**]

Comment: you mean what by *100vh is longer.* ? Actually this is what you need: height:100vh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty straight forward.  vw for viewport width and vh for viewport height

```css
div {
       position: relative;
      
       border-radius: 12px;
       width: 100vw;
       height: 100vh; 
} 
#a1{
background-color:blue;
}
#a2{
background-color:green;
}
#a3{
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id='a1'>
</div>
<div id='a2'>
</div>
<div id='a3'>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, my bad. I combined % and vh... and I got lost with margin/padding.. I am just trying to learn. Thanks!

Comment: if this is working for you kindly accept the answer